# Where is the official forum to look for support for Sakai?

Tags: sakai

I make a Google search on Sakai forums, hoping to find a StackExchange sister site for [Sakai](https://sakaiproject.org), but there's nothing useful for me. My search keywords are [sakai ~forum ~support ~offficial](https://www.google.com/search?q=sakai%20~forum&oq=sakai%20~forum&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=sakai%20~forum%20~support%20~offficial)

I love StackOverflow and would love to have similar forum for Sakai. If you know where to ask such Sakai usage questions, e.g. "how to update questions for published multiple-choices quiz in Sakai", please share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always post like you did here (on stackoverflow with a "sakai" tag) but we have official mailing lists as well. You can find the dev list here:
https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!forum/sakai-dev

For questions like your example, you probably want the user forum:
https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!forum/sakai-user

Or the related wiki space:
https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/USER/Using+Sakai

There is more information on the project wiki:
https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/CONF/Welcome+to+the+Sakai+wiki

Finally, you can look here for more information about Sakai in general:
https://www.apereo.org/Sakai

And:
https://www.sakaiproject.org/

Comment: We tried last year to get an Area 51 going for Sakai/Apereo but there wasn't enough interest to push it into the second phase. Tag your posts sakai on here or use the mailing list as are best suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your full details @azeckoski!

Comment: @jonespm Yeah the google search results pop up some links that point to Area 51 on stackexchange year ago but the page is not available as you said. So sad to know that SAKAI community have little interest on such forum...

Comment: @jonespm I find that question2answer is a very very good web application that is so similar to stackoverflow forum. May we use it to form a better forum for SAKAI? I'm happy to help!